# SQL Server 2008 MAX and MIN function not working as expected with negative numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, max, min, sqldatatypes

I've noticed that the MAX/MIN aggregate functions for SQL Server 2008 do not work as expected with negative numbers.

I was working with latitude and longitude values (many are negative #s) and I'm getting results that appear to only be looking at the absolute value.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(g.Geo_Lat) AS MaxLat, MAX(g.Geo_Long) AS MaxLong,
    MIN(g.Geo_Lat) AS MinLat, MIN(g.Geo_Long) AS MinLong  
FROM Geolocations g
```

Here are results of a query:

```
MaxLat          MaxLong         MinLat        MinLong
38.3346412      -85.7667496     38.1579234    -85.5289429
```

note the results for maxlong and minlong are incorrect.

Is there some workaround for this (other than a special UDF)?

Comment: What's the source data? I guess there is only one row... Anyway, your theory that aggregates operate on ABS values is disproven by the fact that your results include negative numbers.

Comment: I fail to see how max and min have any meaning at all when using lat and long. -137.00 is not smaller than 45, it is just a different spot on a globe. Souther hemisphere latitudes are not inherently smaller than northern hemispher ones.

Comment: HLGEM - Latitude and Longitude individually do have an ordering, and you would expect SQL to be able to order them in that way. This is used if you want to draw a box around all the points in your set - you need to find the southeast and northwest most points, or the equivalent, to have those be the extrema of your box.

Comment: when adjusting the zoom for the Google Maps API (ver3), you need the extrema for their new auto-zoom feature (that frames point markers so all are displayed in the map).  While trying to make only a single call to a SP that returns extra tables, the last table consisting of 4 values: minLat, maxLat, minLong, maxLong.
These are put into an array for the Google fitBounds() function.

Before, I was doing the calculation on the client end - but SQL seems to be more efficient (even though only a handful of markers are shown on the map - the background data can require thousands of points)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Data types and collation determine order.**

Geographic data, stored for instance as a geography type, could sort differently than float values - but in this case, they would not. Gopegraphic types are not sortable, only the latitudes and longitudes are, as you display. But those output as float values.

What data type are you using that causes this to occur? Affter some testing, I eventually figured it out. It would work as expected for geographic data, or any numeric type that holds negative numbers.

**You are storing your latitudes and longitudes as text data - aren't you?**

Cast them as floats. That will fix it.

Comment: Crap! They WERE set as varchars - DOH!

Answer (score 3):

Max and Min aggregates have worked as expected for me in SQL Server 2008. Can you provide the column types for Geolocations table?

It does depend on the locations in your table. As you get more and more entries, it should approach

```
MaxLat          MaxLong             MinLat           MinLong
90              180                 -90              -180
south pole      far west of        north pole       far east of 
                prime meridian                      prime meridian
```

Prime meridian 0 degrees goes through London, England.
-180 and 180 are the same line opposite 0.

Try adding these locations to your table if you only have a few rows:

```
insert into Geolocations (Geo_Lat, GeoLong) values(-180,-90)
insert into Geolocations (Geo_Lat, GeoLong) values(0,0)
insert into Geolocations (Geo_Lat, GeoLong) values(180,90)
```

Comment: Do you know the data types being used?

Comment: No, had to ask in my question as I can't make comments yet (I'm a new user)

Comment: I got the data elsewhere, and, low and behold, the values were not stored as floats (but varchar's) - so, naturally, they are sorted by character. Man, I really need to get more sleep :)